# How would I sort a hierarchical list into a tree/pyrimid model of dicts?

Tags: python, qt, opencv, recursion, hierarchy

I am trying to generate a hierarchy of dicts to use to create a Tree Model in Qt.

The data is in a list with each entry being **[Next Sibling, Previous Sibling, First_Child, Parent]** and the index of the element in the list is the name/index of the contour described by the hierarchy entry.

For example if I were to input the hierarchy from section 4.RETR_TREE [here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_hierarchy/py_contours_hierarchy.html)

```
hierarchy = 
    array([[[ 7, -1,  1, -1],
            [-1, -1,  2,  0],
            [-1, -1,  3,  1],
            [-1, -1,  4,  2],
            [-1, -1,  5,  3],
            [ 6, -1, -1,  4],
            [-1,  5, -1,  4],
            [ 8,  0, -1, -1],
            [-1,  7, -1, -1]]])
```

I would like to get this output:

```
{0:{1:{2:{3:{4:{5:{},6:{}}}}}},
7:{},
8:{}}
```

I am looking to do this to build a tree model in Qt so I can easily see which contours contain which others. If you have a better idea of how to turn the hierarchy data into a Qt tree model that would also be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to @uselpa I'm coming up with a solution that does not sort nodes having the same parent node, since a Python dictionary has no fixed order:

```py
import numpy as np
H = np.array(
    [[ 7, -1,  1, -1],
     [-1, -1,  2,  0],
     [-1, -1,  3,  1],
     [-1, -1,  4,  2],
     [-1, -1,  5,  3],
     [ 6, -1, -1,  4],
     [-1,  5, -1,  4],
     [ 8,  0, -1, -1],
     [-1,  7, -1, -1]])

def T(i):
    children = [(h, j) for j, h in enumerate(H) if h[3] == i]
    children.sort(key = lambda h: h[0][1])
    return {c[1]: T(c[1]) for c in children}

print T(-1)
```

Output:

```
{0: {1: {2: {3: {4: {5: {}, 6: {}}}}}}, 8: {}, 7: {}}
```

Thus you can skip sorting the children and end up with the following compact code:

```
T = lambda i: {j: T(j) for j, h in enumerate(H) if h[3] == i}
print T(-1)
```

Comment: Wow! I see that this works with a plain list of lists, no numpy required. Here's a version for those of us without dict comprehensions: `T = lambda i: dict((j, T(j)) for j, h in enumerate(H) if h[3] == i); print T(-1)`

Answer (score 0):

I not familiar with Qt, numpy or opencv so I'm probably missing something here, but I'll give it a try anyway.

The following algorithm creates the dictionary as requested:

```
def make_hdict(hier):
    def recur(parent):
        res = {}
        for i,n in enumerate(hier):
            if n[3] == parent:
                res[i] = recur(i)
        return res
    return recur(-1)
```

Testing:

```
hierarchy = [[ 7, -1,  1, -1], #0
             [-1, -1,  2,  0], #1
             [-1, -1,  3,  1], #2
             [-1, -1,  4,  2], #3
             [-1, -1,  5,  3], #4
             [ 6, -1, -1,  4], #5
             [-1,  5, -1,  4], #6
             [ 8,  0, -1, -1], #7
             [-1,  7, -1, -1]] #8    
print(make_hdict(hierarchy))
=> {0: {1: {2: {3: {4: {5: {}, 6: {}}}}}}, 8: {}, 7: {}}
```

As you can see, I only use the last field ("Parent") at this point. 
In particular,

1. I am not using "next sibling" and "previous sibling" since a dictionary is unordered
2. I am not using "first child" since it is redundant information.

Is that what you want?